# Send parameters to partial view loaded with .load()

Tags: php, ajax, zend-framework, partial-views

I have a button in my form "Add Question" and when I click on it I load a partial view like this:

```
$("." + classname).load("/partials/question-partial.phtml");
```

The classname is for example "questioncontainer3". But now my question is how can I send parameters to the view and use them in my view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the same load() function, you can simply do:

```
$("." + classname).load("/partials/question-partial.phtml", { "firstfield": "Jon", "secondfield": "Susan" } );
```

Comment: And how can I use the values in the view? I tried <?php echo $this->firstfield ?> but then it shows no partial ...

Comment: Receive them like this now: <?php $questiontypes = $_POST['question_types']; ?>

Comment: Sorry I didn't read it nor understand what you meant no time, but I'm glad that you solved it yourself

Answer (score 1):

Use the [.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function in jquery. You can pass `data` in the `settings` parameter.

`.load()` is a simplified version of this.

In Zend, assuming you're in a controller, you can use:

```
$params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
```

And `$params` will be an array of parameters from `GET` and `POST`.